# How to view exceptions when using asyncio and executor pools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

How can I get the exceptions from different processes to spit out on stdout when using executor pools with asyncio?

For now all exceptions are trapped in the ether and I can only partially dechiper what's going wrong when I kill the script via ctrl-c....

here's some code:

```
import lib.myFunctions
import asyncio
import oandapy


fmc = lib.myFunctions.FmcMixin()


def meatAndPotatoes(currency_pair=sys.argv[1],
    time_compression=sys.argv[2],sleep_time=sys.argv[3]):
    while True:
        try:
            something = oanda.get_history()
            if (something):
                print("niceeee")
            else:
                print("ok cool")
        except:
            sleep(sleep_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(executor, meatAndPotatoes))
    scriptName = str(sys.argv[1] + "/" + sys.argv[2] + "/")
    asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(executor, fmc.heartbeatFunction(scriptName)))
    loop.run_forever()
```

When meatAndPotatoes has problems I can't see the errors till ctrl-c, same as fmc.heartbeatFunction....

Comment: You should add some example code to this question.

Comment: i honestly dont know how to post some code wo posting too much, i personally dont like SO qs that have alot of code in it